# DIV tag keep using 100% width

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a div that contains form that contains table with inputs. Problem is that div keep using width 100% even when I set it to 220px (width:220px).

Here is a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Y2b.jpg

Here is HTML with removed trs and tds

```
<div class="prikol_filter_div">
    <form name="arrFilter_form" action="" method="get" class="prikol_filter_form">
        <table class="data-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <span class="prikol_filter_title">ПОДОБРАТЬ ПОДАРОК</span><hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>trs and tds</tbody>
            <tfoot>trs and tds</tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.prikol_filter_div {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
}

.prikol_filter_form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 222px;
  background-color: #c3150d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  right: 17px;
}
```

There is no other CSS styles applied.

Comment: have you tried width: 222px!important; ??

Comment: The blue area is the `div`s `width` the orange area shows that it is a `block` element so that any element after it will be on a new line. You may want to try floating the `div` if this is undesirable.

Comment: Just tried. Still 100% width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not. it's using the `220px` you assigned it.

Your inspector is also telling you this with the *blue* highlight color.

What you are seeing is the highlighting of your inspector telling you that the rest of the highlighted area is "reserved" because the div is styled like a `block`. (this is the *yellow* highlighting)

It means that if you give that `div` a neighbor element, it will be positioned *below* that `div`.

If you don't want it to reserve this space, use `display:inline-block;`

Check out this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ak6qhh6/1/) for an example with `display:inline-block;`

Comment: That's right, I highlight it to show that space is taken by that div.

Comment: And it shows you that it takes `220px` (the blue highlighted color).
It also shows you that the rest of that line is reserved (the yellow color) because you told it to display like a `block`

Comment: Problem solved by giving _display:inline-block;_ to DIV that was using 100% width and to DIV that suppose to take that empty space (DIV with shoes on the picture).

Answer (score 0):

```
.prikol_filter_div {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 220px!Important;
}

.prikol_filter_form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 222px!Important;
  background-color: #c3150d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  right: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. It's always better to explain what the code does and how it addresses the question. This helps future users.

Answer (score -1):

it can't be the width issue, give a look at this link

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/vipinraunchhela/toos9k96/][1]
```

all your code is in it and its Working fine, if you are still having a problem just add a property to your div **overflow:hidden;** this will hide all the data which are going out of it. their could be a reason if you have define a div property **width:100% !important;** this could be the reason.
if you cant figure out the problem you can use **width:220px !important;**
its not a good practice but for time being you can use this.